# How to make objects public through python code once uplaoded to s3 bucket from ubuntu system using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am new to python and coding. I have a question on making the objects public when uploaded to s3 bucket from ubuntu vm using boto3 in python. I was able to upload files to my s3 bucket however although my bucket is public i am not able to access each object as permission denied. So any help on how to make objects public automatically once uploaded to bucket through this python script? Any links or similar query would be helpful.

```
Below is the sample code I used





#!/usr/bin/env python
    
    import glob
    import boto3
    import os
    
    BUCKET_NAME = 'bucketname'
    FOLDER_NAME = 'foldername'
    
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name='default')
    s3 = session.client('s3')
    
    csv_files = glob.glob("/home/ubuntu/Desktop/scan_reports/*.csv")
    json_files = glob.glob("/home/ubuntu/Desktop/scan_reports/*.json")
    xml_files = glob.glob("/home/ubuntu/Desktop/scan_reports/*.xml")
    txt_files = glob.glob("/home/ubuntu/Desktop/scan_reports/*.txt")
    
    for filename in csv_files:
        key = "%s/%s" % (FOLDER_NAME, os.path.basename(filename))
        print("Putting %s as %s" % (filename,key))
        s3.upload_file(filename, BUCKET_NAME, key)
    
    for filename in json_files:
        key = "%s/%s" % (FOLDER_NAME, os.path.basename(filename))
        print("Putting %s as %s" % (filename,key))
        s3.upload_file(filename, BUCKET_NAME, key)
    
    for filename in xml_files:
        key = "%s/%s" % (FOLDER_NAME, os.path.basename(filename))
        print("Putting %s as %s" % (filename,key))
        s3.upload_file(filename, BUCKET_NAME, key)
    
    for filename in txt_files:
        key = "%s/%s" % (FOLDER_NAME, os.path.basename(filename))
        print("Putting %s as %s" % (filename,key))
        s3.upload_file(filename, BUCKET_NAME, key)
    
    print("All files uploaded to S3")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upload and set permission publicly-readable in single line, you can refer given below example.

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket(S3_BUCKET)    
bucket.upload_file(file, key, ExtraArgs={'ACL':'public-read'}
```

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html#the-extraargs-parameter

Also you can do through ObjectAcl API.

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
object_acl = s3.ObjectAcl('bucket_name','object_key')
response = object_acl.put(ACL='public-read')
```

Note: Use boot3